# Why my fields do not get updated with real time data in tables?

Tags: mysql

I am having a quite strange behavior of my stored procedure.

My testing SQL query is as follows

```
    SET @Latitude = '45.512573';
SET @Longitude = '-122.661276';
SET @OrderDateTime = '2018-11-13 09:23:45';
SET @NumberOFRecords = 6;
SET @RecordsOffSet = 0;

SELECT 
listings.LISTING_MAX_QUANTITY, 
@TOTAL_ORDERS := SUM(order_items.ORDER_QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_ORDERS,
@REMAINING_ORDER_ITEMS := (listings.LISTING_MAX_QUANTITY - @TOTAL_ORDERS) AS REMAINING_ORDER_ITEMS
FROM listings 
INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.ORDER_LISTING_ID = listings.LISTING_ID AND DATE(order_items.ORDER_REQUIRED_DATE_TIME) = DATE(@OrderDateTime)
WHERE listings.LISTING_ID IN (SELECT listing_region.LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID FROM listing_region WHERE listing_region.LIST_REGION_REGION_ID IN (SELECT REGION_ID FROM region WHERE CONTAINS(REGION_POLYGON, point(@Latitude, @Longitude)))) 
AND listings.LISTING_MAX_QUANTITY > 99
AND TIME(@OrderDateTime) BETWEEN LISTING_START_TIME AND LISTING_END_TIME;
```

When I update the order_item tables with quantities, REMAINING_ORDER_ITEMS does not get updated in the first call. It is correct in the second call. Why is that? How does my query remember the last call?

Comment: In such a large query, without any sample data, it is hard to figure out what is happening. It will be best if you setup a fiddle showcasing the problem being faced.

Comment: I need to figure out how to setup fiddle. Never done it. This query works perfectly fine in the second run as I stated. I don't understand is why it does not work in the first run after the table update.

Comment: Please show us how you use this stored procedure, in particular in relation with the update with quantities.

Comment: check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/  ; it is mostly intuitive. You can also click on load example button at top to see how it works

Comment: its the order where Used in JOIN. One the order is setup, it worked.